# Listening and reciveing specific SMS message?

Tags: android, string, sms, broadcastreceiver

Ok i Have this broadcast reciver for Listening incoming SMS

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

            }

            }

            try {
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                if (root.canWrite()){
                File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Bonbon info");
                dir.mkdirs();
                File f = new File(dir, "test.txt");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                out.write(str);
                out.close();
                }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }                         
    }
```

Now, i need to listen only specific SMS messages, that have word "Nemas" or "Potrosio" for the first word in the SMS.Can you help me with this ????

EDIT: I made a mistake, and i didn't ask a right question. I want to recive ALL messages, but only SMS with specific text I need to save into text file ?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I believe this works on all phones, but not tested.

```
Uri allMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(allMessage, new String[]{"body"}, null, null, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            if(c.getColumnName(0).equals("body")){
                String result = c.getString(0);

            }
        }
```

This gets the body from every SMS message stored on the phone. If you only want to see texts from the last hour:

```
String selection = "date>=" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-60*60*1000);

        Uri allMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(allMessage, new String[]{"body"}, null, null, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            if(c.getColumnName(0).equals("body")){
                String result = c.getString(0);

            }
        }
```

from there you should be able to search thru the bodies of the SMSs for what you need or write a query (just like the date example) to search them.