# Reading only specific SMS messages?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, string-comparison

I have a SMS reciver that listens incoming SMS messages and saves text from SMS into File on sdcard. I want to listen all incoming messages, but only specific messages, taht begins with word "Nemas" or "Preostalo" are copied to the text file. How can i do that ??

And second, after i processed specific message, and text is copied into text file on sdcard , can I automaticly set this sms from unread to read ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387305/listening-and-reciveing-specific-sms-message/7387333#7387333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for SMS write to the file store the message content into String object as body. now check whether this will start with "Nemas" or "Preostalo" then write into the txt file.

```
private static final String NEMAS = "Nemas";
private static final String PREOSTALO = "Preostalo";

private String msg;
```

check the message as you first get the message and store into the msg object

```
if(msg.startsWith(NEMAS) || msg.startsWith(PREOSTALO)){

     // write the msg into the txt file

}
```

Comment: startWith() gives error , and offers me to change to startsWith () ?? Is that ok ??

Comment: sorry this was startsWith I forgot the "s" in this